# Pyinstaller problem, when i try to make an exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller

I recently made a small game about some of my friends and when i try to convert it to an exe file, using the auto-py-to-exe project i get an error.When I open the exe file it says "Failed to execute script"
I have some pictures and audios, all the elements are in the same folder.
Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# rezolutia ecranului
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Background
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")

#Background sound
#mixer.music.load("Talent de tigan.mp3")
#mixer.music.play(-1)

# titlu si iconita
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load("vld1.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 515
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range (num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load("urs.png"))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(2)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

# Bullet
bulletImg = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
# ready - nu pot vedea glontu pe ecran
# fire - glontu se misca
bullet_state = "ready"

# Score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font("Fruity Stories.ttf", 32)

textX = 10
textY = 10

# Game over text

over_font = pygame.font.Font("Fruity Stories.ttf", 124)

def show_score(x,y):
    score = font.render("Ursi ucisi :" + str(score_value),True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))

def  game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("Te-a mancat ",True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))

def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))

def fire_bullet(x,y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))

def isCollision(enemyX,enemyY,bulletX,bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX-bulletX,2)) + (math.pow(enemyY-bulletY,2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# sa nu se inchida fereastra
running = True
while running:
   #background  R  G  B
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    #background image
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
#player movement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bullet_sound = mixer.Sound("inreg.wav")
                    bullet_sound.play()
                    #get the current x coordinate of the spaceship
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <=0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >=736:
        playerX = 736
#enemy movement
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):

        #Game Over
        if enemyY[i] > 470:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break


        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <=0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >=736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
         # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            explx_sound = mixer.Sound("mustea4.wav")
            explx_sound.play()
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)
#bullet movement
    if bulletY <=0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change



    player(playerX,playerY)
    show_score(textX,textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you for your time.
I am using Python 3 btw.

Comment: Can you tell us what you typed to convert it?

Comment: Problem is in converation and not in code

Comment: i used the auto py to exe project,  the command that the application created for me is     pyinstaller -y -w  "C:/Users/MyName.MyName-PC/Desktop/jcr/spaceinvaders/main.py"

Comment: This is what I would do to convert the file: ```pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py```.

Comment: I can suggest a tutorial on pyinstaller, maybe try this method, and see it it works. [How to convert py to exe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4).

Comment: `pyinstaller`  has friendly and helpful advice at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add your data files:
If you use windows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-data="background.png;." --add-data="icon.png;."\
#continue adding add-data for all your files
script.py
```

else replace `;` with `:`.
This way pyinstaller knows which files are needed for your game to work and can add them